# SQL Server : query on specific time for week and we

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to run a query that returns data based on their time and date.

- During the week, it will returns data from 17:00 until 09:00.
- During the weekend, it will returns data from 00:00 until 23:59

The data will match a number value

Here is what I've tried but the returned data doesn't take into account the number value

```
SELECT 
    I3TimeStampGMT, DNIS, AssignedWorkGroup, LocalName, RemoteNumber, 
    CallDurationSeconds
FROM
    CIC_Prod.dbo.calldetail_viw 
WHERE 
    (I3TimeStampGMT > '2017-12-01' 
    AND I3TimeStampGMT <= DATEADD(day,1,'2017-12-05') 
    AND (DATEPART(HH,I3TimeStampGMT) IN (18, 07)
         OR (DATEPART(HH,I3TimeStampGMT) = 17 AND DATEPART(MI,I3TimeStampGMT) >= 00) 
         OR (DATEPART(HH,I3TimeStampGMT) = 08 AND DATEPART(MI,I3TimeStampGMT) <= 59)
        )
    AND DATEPART(dw,I3TimeStampGMT) >= 2 AND DATEPART(dw,I3TimeStampGMT) <= 6
        --sun(1)-mon(2)-tue(3)-wed(4)-thu(5)-fri(6)-sat(7)
        )
    OR  I3TimeStampGMT > '2017-12-01' AND I3TimeStampGMT <= DATEADD(day,1,'2017-12-05')
    and (
        DATEPART(HH,I3TimeStampGMT) IN (18, 07)
        OR (DATEPART(HH,I3TimeStampGMT) = 17 AND DATEPART(MI,I3TimeStampGMT) >= 00) 
        OR (DATEPART(HH,I3TimeStampGMT) = 08 AND DATEPART(MI,I3TimeStampGMT) <= 59)
        )
    AND DATEPART(dw,I3TimeStampGMT) >= 7 AND DATEPART(dw,I3TimeStampGMT) <= 7


AND
LineId = 'SIP-100-UK'
AND(
DNIS = '4910045'
OR
DNIS = '4910044'
OR
DNIS = '4910043'
OR
DNIS = '4910025'
OR
DNIS = '4910024'
OR
DNIS = '4910023'
OR
DNIS = '4910021'
OR
DNIS = '4910026'
OR
DNIS = '4910019'
OR
DNIS = '4910022'
OR
DNIS = '4910020'
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter is made using `AND` and `OR`, if one of the conditions in `OR` is true the rest should be `true` or `false`, it does not matter.

In order to take into account the number value, it should be added with `AND` to the previous condition, so you need another pair of parentheses, I evidence it with `--<<<-----` :

```
SELECT 
    I3TimeStampGMT, DNIS, AssignedWorkGroup, LocalName, RemoteNumber, 
    CallDurationSeconds
FROM
    CIC_Prod.dbo.calldetail_viw 
WHERE 
( --<<<------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (I3TimeStampGMT > '2017-12-01' 
    AND I3TimeStampGMT <= DATEADD(day,1,'2017-12-05') 
    AND (DATEPART(HH,I3TimeStampGMT) IN (18, 07)
         OR (DATEPART(HH,I3TimeStampGMT) = 17 AND DATEPART(MI,I3TimeStampGMT) >= 00) 
         OR (DATEPART(HH,I3TimeStampGMT) = 08 AND DATEPART(MI,I3TimeStampGMT) <= 59)
        )
    AND DATEPART(dw,I3TimeStampGMT) >= 2 AND DATEPART(dw,I3TimeStampGMT) <= 6
        --sun(1)-mon(2)-tue(3)-wed(4)-thu(5)-fri(6)-sat(7)
        )
    OR  I3TimeStampGMT > '2017-12-01' AND I3TimeStampGMT <= DATEADD(day,1,'2017-12-05')
    and (
        DATEPART(HH,I3TimeStampGMT) IN (18, 07)
        OR (DATEPART(HH,I3TimeStampGMT) = 17 AND DATEPART(MI,I3TimeStampGMT) >= 00) 
        OR (DATEPART(HH,I3TimeStampGMT) = 08 AND DATEPART(MI,I3TimeStampGMT) <= 59)
        )
    AND DATEPART(dw,I3TimeStampGMT) >= 7 AND DATEPART(dw,I3TimeStampGMT) <= 7
)--<<<------------------------------------------------------------------------------

AND
LineId = 'SIP-100-UK'
AND(
DNIS = '4910045'
OR
DNIS = '4910044'
OR
DNIS = '4910043'
OR
DNIS = '4910025'
OR
DNIS = '4910024'
OR
DNIS = '4910023'
OR
DNIS = '4910021'
OR
DNIS = '4910026'
OR
DNIS = '4910019'
OR
DNIS = '4910022'
OR
DNIS = '4910020'
)
```